# How to extract and print a list of values from my JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I'm working in Python (3.8) and I've successfully called an API gotten it to print the JSON within command line after running the Python file. Now, I want to be able to print a particular list of information (like all of the names from the JSON), and later on save that list as its own set of data, but I'm hitting a block.

Example JSON I'm working with:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "employees": [
      {
        "fields": {
          "name": "Buddy",
          "superheroName": "Syndrome",
          "workEmail": "syndrome@example.com",
        }
      },
      {
        "fields": {
          "name": "Helen Parr",
          "superheroName": "Elastigirl",
          "workEmail": "elastigirl@example.com",
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

I’ve tried the following so far and I was able to get “data” to print, but anytime I try to print another “layer” and get to say...“employees” or “fields” even, I hit a wall.

```
url = "my API url"

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Error with status code {}'.format(response.status_code))
    exit()
           
jsonResponse = response.json()
jsonPretty = json.dumps(jsonResponse, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
jsonDictionary = json.loads(jsonPretty)
keys = jsonDictionary.keys()
for key in jsonDictionary.keys():
    print(key)
```

Ideally, could someone share insight into how I can access the 'name' JSON value and get Python to print it as a list like the following, for example:

```
Buddy
Helen Parr
```

Comment: You are only printing the ```keys```, not the ```values``` (that can be accessed through the ```keys```). Experiment with ```jsonDictionary[key]``` ....

Answer (score 1):

JSON files are basically nested dictionaries. `jsonDictionary` only contains one key and one entry under that key: `data` and another dictionary with the rest your result respectively.

If you wanted to access the `name` fields specifically:

```
employeesDict = jsonDictionary['data']
feildsDictList = employeesDict['employees']

firstFieldsDict = fieldsDictList[0]
secondFieldsDict = fieldsDictList[1]

firstName = firstFieldsDict['name']
secondNAme = secondFieldsDict['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this (make sure it's already a dictionary):

```
for i in h['data']['employees']:
    print(i['fields']['name'])
```

This way you can access the names with i['fields']['name']